# Rails Routing: Remove the edit suffix to url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am creating a website with a blog module. A blog post can either be a draft or published.

A published post can no longer be edited, and a draft cannot be viewed (only edit)

I currently have a resource defined as

```
resources :posts, :path => "blog" do
  collection do
    get 'drafts'
  end
end
```

I can access the drafts list using `blog/drafts`, creating new ones posts using `blog/new`, and editing drafts through `blog/:id/edit`.

However, I'd like new drafts to be created using `blog/drafts/new` and edited using `blog/drafts/:id`

I need to define the `new`, `create`, `edit` and `update` routes to use this new scheme. The `new` and `create` routes seem quite simple. However I do not know how to handle the `edit` route in order to remove the action name part.

Also, while looking at the default routes definition, I found in `actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb` the following :

```
member do
  get    :edit if parent_resource.actions.include?(:edit)
  get    :show if parent_resource.actions.include?(:show)
  [...]
end
```

I do not understand how rails differentiates the `:edit` and the `:show` routes, and map the urls accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following routes. Keep in mind that it requires different file hierarchy, `rake routes` should be your friend in this.

```
namespace :blog do
  resources :drafts, :controller => :posts, only: [:new, :edit]
  resources :posts, only: :show
end
```